# Calling an XQuery function from XForms

Tags: xquery, xforms, exist-db

I'd like to call an XQuery function that I have written from XForms. I know how to execute a request to an XQuery document:

```
<xf:submission resource="/exist/rest/apps/Main/modules/import.xql"/>
```

But what if I'd like to call a specific function in the XQuery document?  It looks like this can be done with JavaScript with `import module namespace` but is there not a way to do this in XForms?

I suppose I can use exist-db's `controller.xql` to handle requests.  Is this the simplest way to do it?

Comment: From XForms, you can post XQuery content to eXist, and eXist will run that. Wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: I was hoping to have a function that I could call from many different xform documents.  I suppose that is why eXist has the url redirect capability though.

Comment: I don't get the URL redirect bit. But why wouldn't you be able to call that XQuery from multiple XForms documents?

Comment: I can.  I was hoping to use an xquery with defined functions in it.  If I just post to the xquery document, it will run whatever is not encased in a function declaration.  I was hoping on using a namespace and calling just a single function in 'import.xql' like 'import:lookup'.  Exist allows you to post to a controller.xql with parameters and then just redirect to whichever query or function I'd like.  I was just hoping for a quicker route than that.

Comment: @zepperik You might want to look into the eXist-db implementation of RESTXQ, a standard that lets users define endpoints that correspond to individual XQuery functions. A [recent thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/exist/mailman/message/34566969/) on the eXist-open list has some helpful links to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't! XForms is not XQuery and there is nothing in the XForms specification that let's you import an XQuery module.

As others have previously suggested you need to use HTTP to bridge the two, and if you want direct access over HTTP to an XQuery function, then RESTXQ is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured as much, but thought I'd ask in case someone else was searching for this answer.